# how to reuse json data

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i have ajax call which is returning data to me .

Say i have ajax returning data

```
$.ajax({
            url : "quoteSearch",
            dataType : "json",
            data : $("#searchCriteria").serialize(),
            success : function(data) {
                populateTable(data);

            },
            error : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Now i want to use this table data to update the UI.

Say if i add 10 to input box. and click go button it should add 10 to all quotes of the column.

How should i do this.

Comment: How is this related to `ajax`?

Comment: Now if i want to send the ajax request with previous ajax data i.e "data" in above example plus one more field in addition to old data . How should i perform this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be asking how to use the `data` returned by the ajax call from another part of your code at a non-specific time depending on when the user clicks a button. If so, you can save `data` in a variable with scope outside the ajax call, then access it from other parts of your code:

```
var ajaxData;

$.ajax({
   url : "quoteSearch",
   dataType : "json",
   data : $("#searchCriteria").serialize(),
   success : function(data) {
      ajaxData = data;
      populateTable(data);
   },
   error : function(data) {
      console.log(data);
   }
});

$("#yourbutton").click(function(){
   // do something with ajaxData
   if (typeof ajaxData != "undefined") {
      var valueToAdd = $("#yourinput").val();
      // your processing here
   }
});
```

The undefined test is to allow for if you click the button before the ajax call has finished at which point `ajaxData` would (obviously) not yet have a value.

You may want to update your `populateTable()` function so that it takes a parameter with the value to add. Then inside your ajax success you set that parameter to 0, but inside your button click handler you set that parameter to the value of your input. Presumably your `populateTable()` function already knows how to retrieve the values from `data`, so you can do the extra addition within that functionality. I really can't advise anything more specific without seeing the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

inside your `populateTable` function, you should use `$.each(data,function(k,v){ ... })` to loop over the data and use the values. Without seeing what is inside `data` or the html you are trying to manipulate, or the `populateTable` function, it is difficult to answer more specifically.